# KeyError when dropping rows from Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I'm trying to drop some rows from a Pandas dataframe because they'd be considered outliers in data. I'm getting a KeyError when trying to drop some rows using the method my professor taught me.

```
gdp_2019_outliers = np.where(df_gdp['2019'] > 6)
df_gdp.drop(gdp_2019_outliers[0], inplace=True)
gdp_2019_outliers_neg = np.where(df_gdp['2019'] < -3)
df_gdp.drop(gdp_2019_outliers_neg[0], inplace=True) # stacktrace points here as the cause

gdp_2020_outliers = np.where(df_gdp['2020'] > 3)
df_gdp.drop(gdp_2020_outliers[0], inplace=True)
gdp_2020_outliers_neg = np.where(df_gdp['2020'] < -15)
df_gdp.drop(gdp_2020_outliers_neg[0], inplace=True)
```

So, I find the outliers using `np.where()`, then pass the list of rows to `drop()`. It seems like it's trying to drop rows that are no longer in the dataframe, though -- like the first two lines of code dropped rows that were somehow refound.

Any ideas? Is there a better way to drop rows using a condition?

Stacktrack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\colto\Documents\Spring 2022\Data Sciences\Module 5\DataWrangling\data_wrangling_project.py", line 104, in <module>
    df_gdp.drop(gdp_2019_outliers_neg[0], inplace=True)
  File "C:\Users\colto\Documents\Spring 2022\Data Sciences\Module 5\DataWrangling\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\colto\Documents\Spring 2022\Data Sciences\Module 5\DataWrangling\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4956, in drop
    return super().drop(
  File "C:\Users\colto\Documents\Spring 2022\Data Sciences\Module 5\DataWrangling\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4279, in drop
###############################################################################################################
    obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
  File "C:\Users\colto\Documents\Spring 2022\Data Sciences\Module 5\DataWrangling\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4323, in _drop_axis
    new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
  File "C:\Users\colto\Documents\Spring 2022\Data Sciences\Module 5\DataWrangling\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 6644, in drop
    raise KeyError(f"{list(labels[mask])} not found in axis")
KeyError: '[152] not found in axis'
```

```
gdp_columns = ['Country Name', '1980', '1990', '2000', '2010', '2018', '2019', '2020']
df_gdp = pd.read_csv(gdp_file, usecols=gdp_columns)
```

Dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/zackerym/gdp-annual-growth-for-each-country-1960-2020

Comment: Will you please show the full traceback in the question?

Comment: Hey, @richardec I added the traceback -- thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Hmm, this is confusing. Will you please provide more of you code? I want to be able to reproduce your dataframe (if it's not proprietary).

Comment: That's actually all there is, really. I've added the data source and the remaining lines of code as an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create the source DataFrame as:

```
   2019  2020
0     5     2
1     6     7
2     7   -15
3     8     8
4    -4     5
5    -3   -18
6    -2     7
7    -5    -3
```

So far the index contains consecutive integers, starting from *0*.

When you compute *gdp_2019_outliers*, the result is:

```
(array([2, 3], dtype=int64),)
```

And after the first drop *df_gdp* contains:

```
   2019  2020
0     5     2
1     6     7
4    -4     5
5    -3   -18
6    -2     7
7    -5    -3
```

So far your code succeeded, because integer indices of rows are just
the same as in the index of *df_gdp*.

Then, when you compute *gdp_2019_outliers_neg*, the result is:

```
(array([2, 5], dtype=int64),)
```

Now, when you attempt tu run:

```
df_gdp.drop(gdp_2019_outliers_neg[0], inplace=True)
```

an exception is thrown:

```
KeyError: '[2] not found in axis'
```

The reason why your code failed is that:

- *np.where* finds **integer** indices of the rows found,
  again starting from *0* and not corresponding to the **index**
  of *df_gdp*,
- but then *drop* attempts to find rows with just these values
  **in the index** and this index does not contain *2*.

The proper code should be to use *boolean indexing*:

```
gdp_2019_outliers = df_gdp['2019'] > 6
df_gdp = df_gdp[~gdp_2019_outliers]
```

Then, to drop negative outliers for *2019*, run:

```
gdp_2019_outliers_neg = df_gdp['2019'] < -3
df_gdp = df_gdp[~gdp_2019_outliers_neg]
```

The result, after both drops, is:

```
   2019  2020
0     5     2
1     6     7
5    -3   -18
6    -2     7
```

Proceed the same way to drop other outliers.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `drop`, you need to pass it row indexes or column names. You can pass it a mask, which is essentially what you're doing.

Try this instead:

```
gdp_2019_outliers = np.where(df_gdp['2019'] > 6)
df_gdp.drop(gdp_2019_outliers[0], inplace=True)
gdp_2019_outliers_neg = np.where(df_gdp['2019'] < -3)
# Use this line instead:
df_gdp = df_gdp[~gdp_2019_outliers_neg[0]]


gdp_2020_outliers = np.where(df_gdp['2020'] > 3)
df_gdp.drop(gdp_2020_outliers[0], inplace=True)
gdp_2020_outliers_neg = np.where(df_gdp['2020'] < -15)
# Use this line instead as well:
df_gdp = [~gdp_2020_outliers_neg[0]]
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Python, but I get a "TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'tuple'" error when using it this way.